# How to copy material texture settings between faces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I'm currently trying to create a scene in blender based of minecraft (because why not) and I'm having difficulty with texturing objects. I split the faces of the objects to that each face would be 1 block. I added a png image as the texture of the face and adjusted the uv to fit the face of the object. Is there a way I can copy the uv settings between faces? Because manually going in and fixing the uv for each face would be a nightmare.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: what if you unwrapped all these faces together? They would overlap and you could align them all together with your image, no?

Answer (score 1):

Following @moonboots' suggestion: If you  select all the faces to be mapped identically, and <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap them together, with the 'Reset' option, they will all be mapped to the full (0,0) > (1,1)  UV space. You can then line them all up together.

The shipped 'Magic UV' add-on collection also provides an option to copy and paste UVs, either between individual faces, or between ordered selections. if you copy > [default] a single face, you can then select  destination faces, and paste > [default] (N:M) the UVs into all of them.